# Linq to sql - DateTime to Time

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, datetime

I've got a sql table which has a column with the type **Time**. My class representing this table has a property of the type **DateTime**. This property only holds the time, so normaly it looks something like **0001-01-01 06:30:00**.
Now i want to add a new row with this DateTime set, but when submitting changes, I get an **SqlTypeException** which says: **SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM**

Is there a way to insert only the Time into the table and it converts that automatically?

Thnaks for your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use `TimeSpan` in the first place? But you can also get the `TimeSpan` from the `DateTime` via [`DateTime.TimeOfDay`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.timeofday(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
TimeSpan timeOfDay = dt.TimeOfDay;
```

`TimeSpan` is the correct [.NET mapping type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc716729(v=vs.110).aspx) for a `Time` column.